# Search for a specific pattern

Tags: vba, excel

Below VBA finds the most recently modified file in a specific location then copies that file to another location:

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

Dim strcopyfile As String
Dim strpaste As String
Dim strName As String
Dim varDate As Variant

strcopyfile = "C:\Flow"
strpaste = "C:\Users\Draft.xlsx"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strcopyfile)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If objFile.DateLastModified > varDate Then
        varDate = objFile.DateLastModified
        strName = objFile.Name

        FileCopy objFile, strpaste

    End If
Next 'objFile
```

Is there a way of only copying specifically worded files?

Something similar to the `LIKE` function in SQL, e.g.: `WHERE City LIKE 's%'`.

Comment: Yea, you can do `if strName like`

Comment: `If objFile.Name Like "s*" Then`

Answer (score 0):

As you already have strName to hold the filename, you can use the built in INSTR function to test if a string contains a substring. INSTR takes these paramaters:

The position of the string to start searching, 
The string itself,
The string to search for,
How to search (vbTextCompare [case insensitive] and vbBinaryCompare [case sensitive] are the two relevant enums here)

INSTR will then return a number indicating the position of the found string, or 0 if the string was not found. For example;

```
strName = "this is a test file.txt"

?INSTR(1,strName,"test file",vbTextCompare)
```

Will return 11 as 'test file' appears at the 11th position.

So to build in your code, I would add an if statement to run the copy command:

```
If Instr(1,strName,"test file",vbTextCompare) > 0 then
    FileCopy objFile, strpaste
end if
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think Tim's comment is more straightforward, implying the use of an `and` in the `if` statement for modified date.